# Can't set state in componentWillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am creating a simple chat app where I make an api call to my database via axios which returns an array of message objects. I am able to get the data when I make an axios call in componentWillMount. Then I am trying to setState to display the conversation. Here's the code:

```
export default class Chat extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      messages : [],
      message : '',
    };
    this.socket = io('/api/');
    this.onSubmitMessage = this.onSubmitMessage.bind(this);
    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get(`api/messages`)
      .then((result) => {
        const messages = result.data
        console.log("COMPONENT WILL Mount messages : ", messages);
        this.setState({ 
          messages: [ ...messages.content ] 
        })
  })
};
```

I have seen some posts concerning lifecycle functions and setting state, and it seems like I'm doing the right thing.

Again to highlight, axios call working fine, setting the state is not working. I am still seeing an empty array. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is the solution to my issue specifically. It was buried in a comment, so I thought I'd leave it here..

"I discovered the issue. It was actually in how I was parsing my data. The spread operator on ...messages.content didn't work because messages.content doesn't exist. messages[i].content exists. So my fix was to spread just ...messages Then in a child component I map over the objects and parse the .content property. Thanks for the help guys!"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**In your case, your `setState()` won't work because you're using `setState()` inside an async callback**

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xytma20g/3/

You're making an API call which is async. So, the `setState` will be invoke only after receiving the data. It does not do anything with `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount`. You need to handle the empty `message` in your render. When you receive your data from the API, set that data to the state and component will re-render with the new state which will be reflected in your render.

Pseudo code:

```
export default class Chat extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      messages : [],
      message : '',
    };
    this.socket = io('/api/');
    this.onSubmitMessage = this.onSubmitMessage.bind(this);
    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get(`api/messages`)
      .then((result) => {
        const messages = result.data
        console.log("COMPONENT WILL Mount messages : ", messages);
        this.setState({ 
          messages: [ ...messages.content ] 
        })
  })

  render(){
    if(this.state.messages.length === 0){
     return false //return false or a <Loader/> when you don't have anything in your message[]
    }

   //rest of your render.
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm trying to pull up the conversation when I make the get request so the conversation will persist on reload. It seems that the loader will give me a "no new messages" prompt and only render new messages that I input from there on out. I was also thinking of making the GET request at a higher level component so the messages are rendered in state. Here's what my render method looks like now

Comment: I discovered the issue. It was actually in how I was parsing my data. The spread operator on ...messages.content didn't work because messages.content doesn't exist. 

messages[i].content exists. So my fix was to spread just ...messages

Then in a child component I map over the objects and parse the .content property.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @PhilSeidel You're a rockstart. Keep it up.

Answer (score 1):

> componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It
>   is called before render(), therefore setting state in this method will
>   not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any side-effects or
>   subscriptions in this method. [docs](http://componentWillMount()%20is%20invoked%20immediately%20before%20mounting%20occurs.%20It%20is%20called%20before%20render(),%20therefore%20setting%20state%20in%20this%20method%20will%20not%20trigger%20a%20re-rendering.%20Avoid%20introducing%20any%20side-effects%20or%20subscriptions%20in%20this%20method.)

So, You need to call `componentDidMount` as-

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`api/messages`)
      .then((result) => {
        const messages = result.data
        console.log("COMPONENT WILL Mount messages : ", messages);
        this.setState({ 
          messages: [ ...messages.content ] 
        })
  })
```

Comment: You point is valid. But, React will use the new state value for the first render instead of re-render. That is the meaning of the statement *method will not trigger a re-rendering*. For your clarification, I'm adding a working example. https://jsfiddle.net/q25sfL0z/

Comment: what if your API call took too much time to return response?

Comment: In that case you should use a loader to indicate the user.

Comment: I catch here is, initial render and re-renders are different. Otherwise, your point is valid!