# React Initial Render Success vs Second Render Failure?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an inventory component linked to an inventory Firebase. When my component renders for the first time it works perfectly. When I leave the inventory page and come back, however, my component only renders the last item in the inventory database. It is also weird because when I include the `console.log('add fired ' + product.data.name);` it recognizes every node in the database and logs the product name, but they are still not displayed on the screen. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
componentWillMount(){
  //Create reference to inventory db
   this.inventory = firebase.database().ref('inventory');

   this.inventory.on('child_added', snapshot => {
      let product = { data: snapshot.val(), id: snapshot.key };
      console.log('add fired ' + product.data.name);
      this.setState({ products: this.state.products.concat(product) });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40199596/6554834. 
componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore setting state in this method will not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.

Comment: So I am extremely new to React and I am not quite sure I understand. Why does it work initially, but not when I return to the page? I tried moving it into `componentDidMount()` but with the same result of it only rendering the last item in the database.

Comment: Does your component unmount from the DOM on moving to another page? If unmounting does not happen, then you are actually updating the already mounted component. In that case , `componentDidUpdate() `will be called instead of `componentWillMount()`. May be you should have a look at the lifecycle methds of React. [React-Life-Cycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)