# Conditional rendering react native :only else part is working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, conditional-rendering

I've done a conditional rendering statement within react.The condition that I'm checking is based on the server response. If the condition is met then I've to render some UI components otherwise a different UI. So the problem is what ever I'm getting from server, only the else portion is working.I've double checked the `response` also.

**updated code**

```
export default class ViewStatus extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.initialState = {
        progressData: [],
        };
        this.state = this.initialState;
    }
    componentWillMount(){
       fetch('http://192.168.1.2:3000/api/progress',{
         method:'POST',
         headers:{
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type':'application/json'
         },
         body:JSON.stringify({
           work_type:this.props.work_type
         })
       })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
         this.setState({
      progressData:responseData[0]
      });
    });
  }
render() {
const isResponseData = this.state.progressData == '1' ? this.renderDone() : this.renderInProgress()
 console.log(this.state.progressData);
  return(
     <View>
        {isResponseData}
      </View>
    );
  }
  renderInProgress(){
    return(
        <View>
          <Text>In Progress</Text>
          <Text>Worker will approach you within 24 hrs.</Text>
       </View>
     );
  }
  renderDone(){
    return(
       <View>
        <Text>Successfull</Text>
        <Text>Are you satisfied with the work .If yes please mark done.</Text>
       </View>
     );
  }
```

Comment: Can you check what you're getting from the server? Have a breakpoint or console.log there

Comment: do you update the state when you get the response ?

Comment: first check the type of this.state.progressData value in console, if its integer then use === 1 or if its string use === '1'. or if values will be 0 or 1 only then no need to use compare operator, u can directly apply. (this.state.progressData)? 'true case' : 'false case';

Comment: Yes I consoled the `progressData` within render.I'm getting an empty array initially but then I'm getting response.Why like that please do check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7Xgi.png . Also updated my code above

Comment: Also I've one more condition to write how do I write with conditional rendering here?

Comment: try using componentDidMount instead of componentwillmount

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199151/cant-set-state-in-componentwillmount

Comment: But I tried with `componentDidMount` even though I'm getting the same.Initially the array will be empty but then I will get value.Is there any problem in setting the state as array in starting of my code?

Comment: If `progressData` is an array your condition should be `this.state.progressData.length > 0`

Comment: progressData has a member "status", shouldn't you check progressData.status?

Comment: @AlexG That's why I'm setting `progressData:responseData[0] ` within the promise of fetch.

Comment: @RaviRupareliya Okay I'll check that ,but what do If I've one more condition that means `status=3`?

Comment: @anu you can use `&&` for and conditions `this.state.progressData.length>0 && status==3`

Comment: No what I meant is an `else if ` condition. `if (status === '1){ render some ui } else if(status === '2'){ render som ui} else { render some ui}`. I'm trying to do something like this .But here when I've checked with `if else` condition only , the else part is working.I think that might be some issue with setting the `progressData` as a state.Because as I've told earlier I'm getting an empty array initially , then only the value is getting.What would be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. You need to call responseData[0].status to get the value from API.
> 2. API calls should happen in componentDidMount only
> 3. componentWillMount is deprecated so forget about this method
> 4. Just use ternary operator to render content instead of multiple functions.

Try with below code.

```
export default class ViewStatus extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {progressData: ""};
    }
    componentDidMount(){
       fetch('http://192.168.1.2:3000/api/progress',{
         method:'POST',
         headers:{
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type':'application/json'
         },
         body:JSON.stringify({
           work_type:this.props.work_type
         })
       })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseData => {
         this.setState({
      progressData:responseData[0].status
      });
    });
  }
render() {
const { progressData }= this.state;
  return(
     <View>
        {progressData == "1" &&
         (<View><Text>Successfull</Text>
        <Text>Are you satisfied with the work .If yes please mark done.</Text></View>)}
    {progressData == "2" &&
         (<View><Text>Successfull</Text>
        <Text>Are you satisfied with the work .If yes please mark done.</Text></View>)}
         {progressData == "" &&(<View><Text>In Progress</Text>
          <Text>Worker will approach you within 24 hrs.</Text></View>)}
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes tried this code but nothing is rendered.I have a doubt , is there any problem in setting the state as array in my code? I will explain you clearly I will be directing to this screen when clicking on a button in the previous page.So how do I manage the fetching here in this page ? Should I use `ComponentDidMount` for that?Because when I consoled response from server the initial response will be empty array. Then only I will be getting the response.So how do I manage that here?Because I think when checking the condition it will take this empty array.Please guide me..

Comment: @anu what you get in the api response? an array or an object with status key? do console log and share the api response

Comment: @anu looks like you are getting object

Comment: This is the response I'm getting when I consoled before  https://i.stack.imgur.com/alffv.png

Comment: But there is  a syntax error in this code `adjacent jsx elements must be wrapped`

Comment: @anu Sorry my bad I missed that. Updated my answer

Comment: Wow..great..It worked thank you so much...How do I check one more condition here? That means now I'm checking whether `status == 1` or the else. How to check else if condition?Because I'm trying to render some UI.In the case of `Pending` , `Inprogress`  and finally `done`

Comment: @anu You are welcome. I updated my answer please have a look

Comment: I'm trying to render different UI for each `status` response. Will it work?Like this `if(status == '1') {renderPending()} else if(status=2){render some ui} else {rendr some ui}`. Could you help?

Comment: Yeah but there is a syntax error please chechk this https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5L87.png

Comment: In the screenshot parent <View> is missing after return(<View>

Comment: Aww.. sorry that was my typo..Thank you so much. :)

Comment: @ThinkTwice Sorry I've a doubt ,If the response I'm fetching contains one more data other than `status` , say `user_id` so I need to  map over it  right? Also will it be like this within the rendering ? `(a.status == "2" ) && (a.user_id == this.state.responseData) &&( render some ui)`.Because in future expansion of my prjct there is a possibility of taking the `user_id` also so please don't feel  that I'm keep asking doubts again and again.Please help

Comment: Is it Single Object with both status and user_id keys or two different objects?

Comment: I mean a single object with keys status and user_id.Because now after conditional rendering I'm displaying some text , along with that I wan't to display the uer_id also.